# Applied JavaScript validations on submit field in JSP but if else code doesn't working

Tags: javascript, validation, jsp

Error = validation function didn't called.
My validation function didnt work.
Can someone help to optimize code or reply the optimized validation code properly.
Thanks in advance.

I am using Eclipse Luna Service Release 1 (4.4.1), tomcat 7, crome browese and XAMPP
Here is my code

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"             "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>


<script type="text/javascript">

function validateForm(){


var firstname=document.getElementById("fname").value;
firstname.trim();
var lastname=document.getElementById("lname").value;
lastname.trim();
var emailid=document.getElementById("email").value;
emailid.trim();
var conatctnumber=document.getElementById("cont").value;
cont.trim();
//alert(firstname+lastname+emailid+conatctnumber);

if(firstname_validation(firstname)){
if(lastname_validation(lastname)){
    if(emailid_validation(emailid)){
        if(contactnumber_validation(contactnumber)){
            return true;
        }
        else{
            return false;
        }
    }

}

}

}


function firstname_validation(firstname){
var letters = /^[A-Za-z]+$/;  
if(firstname.match(letters))  
{ 

return true;  
}  
else  
{  
alert('firstname must have alphabet characters only');  
fname.focus();    
return false;  
}
}

function lastname_validation(lastname){
var letters = /^[A-Za-z]+$/;  
if(lastname.match(letters))  
{ 

return true;  
}  
else  
{  
alert('lastname must have alphabet characters only');  
lastname.focus();  
return false;  
}
} 


function emailid_validation(emailid){
var mailformat=/^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/;
if(emailid.match(mailformat)){
    return ture;
}
else{
    alert("Enter correct email address");
    emailid.focus();
    return false;
}

}

function contactnumber_validation(contactnumber){
var letters="/^\d{10}$/";
if(contactnumber.match(letters)){
    return true;
}
else{
    alert("enter valid contact number");
    contactnumber.focus();
    return false;
}

}


</script>

</head>

<body>

<form name="myform" action="UserServlet" method="post"  >
<input style="display: none;" type = "text" name="userid" value="<c:out      value="${update.userid} ">  </c:out>"><br>

First Name:<br>
<input type = "text" id="fname" name="firstname" value="<c:out    value="${update.firstname} "></c:out>" maxlength="40" required><br>

Last Name:<br>
<input type = "text" id="lname" name="lastname" value="<c:out   value="${update.lastname} "></c:out>" maxlength="40" required><br>
EmailId:<br>
<input type="text" id="email" name="emaild" value="<c:out  value="${update.emailid} "></c:out>" maxlength="50" required><br>

Contact Number:<br>
<input type="text" id="cont" name="contactnumber" value="<c:out          value="${update.contactnumber}"></c:out>"   maxlength="10"  required><br>

<input type="button" value="submit" onClick="return validateForm()">

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you should add an return false at the end of your `validateForm()` function

Comment: didnt work. even I removed return statements from innermost loops. Not worked

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the undeclared variable cont is creating problem for you in following portion of code

```
var conatctnumber=document.getElementById("cont").value;
cont.trim();
```

Change it to below,

```
var conatctnumber=document.getElementById("cont").value;
conatctnumber.trim();
```

You are calling trim function but it is not setting trimmed value back to variable to do that change below

```
var firstname=document.getElementById("fname").value;
firstname.trim();
var lastname=document.getElementById("lname").value;
lastname.trim();
var emailid=document.getElementById("email").value;
emailid.trim();
var conatctnumber=document.getElementById("cont").value;
conatctnumber.trim();
```

to this,

```
var firstname=document.getElementById("fname").value;
firstname = firstname.trim();
var lastname=document.getElementById("lname").value;
lastname = lastname.trim();
var emailid=document.getElementById("email").value;
emailid = emailid.trim();
var conatctnumber=document.getElementById("cont").value;
conatctnumber = conatctnumber.trim();
```

For alphabet validation you can use following regex, this goes for both your firstname and lastname column

```
letters='[A-Za-z]';
```

you are passing emailId value to emailid_validation function and it can not grab the focus

```
function emailid_validation(emailid){
var mailformat=/^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/;
if(emailid.match(mailformat)){
    return ture;
}
else{
    alert("Enter correct email address");
    emailid.focus();
    return false;
}

}
```

change above code to this

```
function emailid_validation(emailid){
var mailformat=/^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/;
mailformat='[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,3}$';
if(emailid.match(mailformat)){
    return true; //corrected Typo here
}
else{
    alert("Enter correct email address");
    document.getElementById("email").focus();
    return false;
}
```

same is applicable for contactnumber_validatio, change below

```
function contactnumber_validation(contactnumber){
var letters="/^\d{10}$/";
if(contactnumber.match(letters)){
    return true;
}
else{
    alert("enter valid contact number");
    contactnumber.focus();
    return false;
}

}
```

to this

```
function contactnumber_validation(contactnumber){
var letters="/^\d{10}$/";
if(contactnumber.match(letters)){
    return true;
}
else{
    alert("enter valid contact number");
    document.getElementById("cont").focus();
    return false;
}

}
```

Change regex from contactnumber_validation from this

```
var letters="/^\d{10}$/";
```

to this

```
var letters=/^\d{10}$/;
```

Comment: yes form submitted. firstname validation worked but lastname emailid contact number validations didnt worked

Comment: which are they?

Comment: @chaitanyaanpat I have updated the answer please check.

Comment: @chaitanyaanpat whats bothering now?

Comment: clicked on submit after that it didn't call validation code

Answer (score 0):

There are several typo issues issues.

As Parth Kale mentioned :

```
var conatctnumber=document.getElementById("cont").value;
cont.trim();
...
                if (contactnumber_validation(contactnumber)) {
```

`cont` and `contactnumber` are not declared anywhere. You should use `contactnumber` since it seems the only correctly spelled variable.

```
var contactnumber=document.getElementById("cont").value;
contactnumber.trim();
...
```

There is also another obvious typo:

```
if(emailid.match(mailformat)){
    return ture;
}
```

will become...

```
if(emailid.match(mailformat)){
    return true;
}
```

You are calling `focus()`on `string` variable**s** instead of DOM element**s**.
For example

```
lastname.focus();
```

Should become...

```
document.getElementById("lname").focus();
```

(You can do that with all your inputs and you can fix another typo. I let you find it :))

Furthermore, you are using the HTML5 `required` attribute while your `doctype` sets the HTML version to 4.01. It would be worth using  `<!DOCTYPE>` to get profit of HTML5 features.

May I suggest you to more intensively use your browser's developer tools (press F12) to debug your code.

You should also indent your code properly. You editor/IDE certainly can reformat it for you.

Comment: thanks a lot. I will read more. I cleared my issues. Thanks again bro

Comment: @chaitanyaanpat Don't forget to accept the answer if it solved your problem